# Dynamic textarea refresh with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Summary: I'm looking for a simple method to refresh a textarea on changes to an HTML form without refreshing the page.

Details:
I'm writing an app to generate standardised BBCode formatting for a forum using data pulled from a database.  It's a non-simple vote counter; I pull in a list of eligible voters and what option they're voting for, and have a vote count that shows each option followed by how many votes it has and a list of who is voting for them, followed by a list of people not yet voting.

Above the textarea, I want a line for each voter with a dropdown box of eligible vote choices, and when the user changes the value of the dropdown box, I want the vote count in the textarea to update without refreshing the entire page.

Is this possible with just PHP5 and HTML5?

Comment: I'm almost sure you have to use js or jquery. why you want to stick with php/html5 only?

Comment: no it is not possible by php or html only. You have to use Ajax if you don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: You can use `action=""` when using a form, which is another method besides Ajax. The only catch is that your entire code would need to be inside the same file. Ajax/JS would be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5dah5/23/

This code should get you started:

```
<script>
function changeText(choice) {
    // or just by js
    $('#myTextarea').val(choice+" modified test").show();

    // send choice to php file and get response back, insert that into the textarea
    // $.get('do.php?file='+choice, function(data) {
    // $('#myTextarea').html(data);
    // });
}    
</script>


<select onChange="changeText(this.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
<hr>
<textarea id="myTextarea">Test</textarea>
```

Now you have to options of modifying the choice:

1. with Javascript on client-side
2. or pass the choice to the server and let PHP give you the response for that choice

Add Jquery to the head of your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```